# Visual Studio Cordova tools using Google Canary

Tags: google-chrome, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to use Visual Studio tools for Cordova, but deployment to Ripple fails saying, "Chrome must be installed in order to launch the app in Ripple". I am using Google Chrome Canary. Is there a setting somewhere that can override the search for Google Chrome standard?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the below reg key to point to custom location like Chrome Canary application location "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe"
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\shell\open\command**

Comment: I don't have that key, since Chrome standard is not there. I added it and validated that VS is reading the value using Process Monitor, but it still is showing the same message. If I remove they key VS does not look for it. It seems VS is just walking the StartMenuInternet keys under HKCU and HKLM, and it finds Canary in HKCU and appears to be inspecting Canary's chrome.exe.

Comment: Currently Visual Studio looks file path %PROGRAMFILES%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe or following reg values to find out whether Chrome is installed or not --      a. ) HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe      b.) HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome\shell\open\command    c.) HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe

Answer (score 0):

try to change a register value
REGISTER LOCATION: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome
Change value for '(Default)' from 'Chrome' to 'Google Chrome'

Details are written in my blog, however, written in Korean.

http://hyunjong-lee.github.io/tech/2015/02/04/Apache_Cordova.html